# Best way to save and retrieve UIColors to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, uicolor

I can think of a few ways, for instance saving each color component as a float, saving an array as transformable. Saving a color from pattern image could be slightly more complicated, but I guess you could save the name of the image as a string and insert that into creation code.

Am I on the right track, else what is the best and most efficient to do this task in general?

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver is the thing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convert your `UIColor` to `NSData` and then store it:

```
NSData *theData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

then you can convert it back to your `UIColor` object:

```
UIColor *theColor = (UIColor *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```

**UPD.:**

Answering your question in comments about storing the data, the most simple way is to store it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSData *theData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theData forKey:@"myColor"];
```

and then retrive it:

```
NSData *theData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
UIColor *theColor = (UIColor *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```

Comment: Thanks! And you would save this to disk directly in the docs dir, or save it as binary data or other in Core Data? I assume either is possible, just wondering what you are thinking of.

Comment: Well, the simplest way would be store it in NSUserDefaults, but other ways are also possible

Answer (score 12):

I have made **Swift 3** version of Oleg's answer with some modifications on the code.

```
extension UIColor {
    func color(withData data:Data) -> UIColor {
         return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! UIColor
    }
    
    func encode() -> Data {
         return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    }
}
```

**Swift 5 version of Extension**

```
extension UIColor {
        
     func color(data:Data) -> UIColor? {
          return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor
     }

     func encode() -> Data? {
          return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var myColor = UIColor.green
// Encoding the color to data
let myColorData = myColor.encode() // This can be saved into coredata/UserDefaulrs
let newColor = UIColor.color(withData: myColorData) // Converting back to UIColor from Data
```

Comment: The extension with .unarchiiveObject is depreciated in swift 5, and compiles with a spiral of errors. @Anand - (or anyone) do you know how to solve this in swift 5?