# How to programmatically change UILabel text color to not predefined swift color?

Tags: swift

```
let color = UIColor.color(withData: plane.color! as Data)
self.deviationLabel.textColor = color
self.deviationLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f m", deviationValue)
```

I know that the first line creates needed color because I draw a line using it, and everything works well. Also if I use a predefined color like `UIColor.red`, the color is changing correctly. So the actual question is how to apply custom color to `UILabel.textColor`?

Comment: What is this `UIColor.color(withData:)` method? What do you get if you print `color`? What is your actual issue?

Comment: it's a custom method, which is working because I use that color to draw a line, and as I said the color is right.
extension UIColor {
    class func color(withData data:Data) -> UIColor {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! UIColor
    }
    
    func encode() -> Data {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    }
}

Comment: Again, what do you get if you print `color`? And what is your actual problem? You never state what your issue is with the code you posted.

Comment: the issue is that the color of uilabel does not change if `label.textColor = color` is applied

Comment: ... the custom method seems to come from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800750/4573247), then?

Comment: the result of `print` is `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 49 8 43 1`

Comment: Try a color that isn't in the extended color space (in other words, ensure each RGB value is between 0.0 and 1.0).

Comment: @dfri yes it was taken from that answer

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! I just don't understand why does it work in the other place in code then. its the same color, just used for the other object