# Store and retrieve UIColor from Core Data using swift 5

Tags: core-data, uicolor, nskeyedarchiver

The answers to the following questions are partially depreciated: **[Storing UIColor object in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835093/storing-uicolor-object-in-core-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)** and [Best way to save and retrieve UIColors to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230720/best-way-to-save-and-retrieve-uicolors-to-core-data?noredirect=1&lq=1).

1) 'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead

2) 'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

```
extension UIColor 
{
   class func color(withData data:Data) -> UIColor 
   { return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! UIColor }

   func encode() -> Data 
   { return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self) }
}
```

Trying to follow the compiler instructions and documentation, I can't get rid of errors. Could someone please clarify the correct equivalent for the above extension methods in Swift 5?

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following for **Swift 5**

```
extension UIColor {

     class func color(data:Data) -> UIColor? {
          return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor
     }

     func encode() -> Data? {
          return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
     }
}
```